# Jenkins script for downloading artifact from nexus and place it in a folder using gradle script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

How to download an artifact from nexus and place it in a folder  using gradle script

Comment: Your question is very brief. Could you elaborate a bit? What are you trying to achieve? And what did you already try?

Comment: i want to download the artifact from nexus to run my CD pipeline in jenkins

Answer (score 0):

Running Gradle in Jenkins: https://guides.gradle.org/executing-gradle-builds-on-jenkins/

How to copy artifacts from nexus to the file system with Gradle: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-i-copy-artifacts-from-nexus-to-local-filesystem/6296